# "Filters" of associative rings

Tags: ring-theory, definition, filters

Does there exist some good notion of "filters" for arbitrary associative rings with unity that would generalize [filters of Boolean rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)#Ideals_and_filters)?

For me, if $R$ is an associative ring with unity $1$, it would seem natural to define a *filter* of $R$ as any subset of the form $1 + I$, where $I$ is a (two-sided) ideal of $R$.

(This question is in a sense a follow-up to [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41358/ideals-and-filters).)

Comment: Other possibly meaningful definitions of a filter: (1) a set of the form $R^\times+I$, where $R^\times$ is the group of units of $R$, (2) a set of the form $H+I$, where $H$ is a subgroup of $R^\times$, (3) a set of the form $N+I$, where $N$ is a normal subgroup of $R^\times$.